# New react-native-app with react-native 0.59.9 or lower

Tags: react-native, epub.js

What is the best/easiest way to create new react-native-app using react-native-0.59.9 or lower?

Trying to use https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn , which only runs in react-native 0.59 or lower.
The example app in https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn/EpubReader does not work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to start a new project with a specific React Native version, you can use the `--version`

```
react-native init ProjectName --version="0.59.9"
```

[Check official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) for more information.

**EDIT**

But in order to run an older version, you need to downgrade your React Native CLI version according to [Compatibility](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#compatibility) of React Native CLI.

If you have already installed a version of react-native CLI, uninstall it using

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Then you have to install an older version as below,

```
npm install react-native-cli@1.0.0
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does not work because cannot successfully run react-native that supports version 0.59.9, because only react-native-cli version 1.xxx supports it. 
Therefore only 0.60.0 works fine with the above.

refer to https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#compatibility

The problem is I cannot install react-native-community/cli v1.xxx successfully.

Could you please try @SDushan? and try to deploy to android.

Comment: @DonCh I have changed my answer. let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

please use [epubjs-rn-62](https://github.com/Arnoldnuo/epubjs-rn#readme)

**usage**
To use the components in your own app install via npm or yarn

```
npm install --save epubjs-rn


import { Epub } from 'epubjs-rn';
```

Then you can add the reader element in your code:

```
<Epub src={"https://s3.amazonaws.com/epubjs/books/moby-dick/OPS/package.opf"}
      flow={"paginated"} />
```